# ag-grid - Refresh on Page Load

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using the JavaScript version of ag-grid to display data on my page.  When I update data on a different page and come back to this one, it still shows the cached data from before.  If I hit `ctrl+F5` it will then refresh.  Is there a way to either get it to not cache anything or to refresh on page load?  Seems like a simple setting that I'm not seeing.

Update: So I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the cache.  It seems like it will refresh that data under circumstances.  If I have the dev tools open (Internet Explorer 11), then it will refresh the data with no problem.  Seems like a strange thing, not sure if it's browser related or not.

Update 2: It's turns out that it wasn't ag-grid but the way I was querying the data.  If you are using jQuery.ajax make sure the cache is setup properly ><.

Answer (score 1):

What caching (HTTP) headers is your data source returning?

You want it to be returning certain headers that tell the browser that the response should not be cached.

For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Examples

Look up how to set caching settings with your web server, etc.

Comment: It was the datasource I was using and it was caching the data, not ag-grid.  I think it's just been one of those days for me.

Comment: I see. From your edit in the question - you don't generally want to set `cache: false` for `jQuery.ajax`. If you need to, it means that your server is indeed returning incorrect caching headers. The best solution is to fix the server, but you can get away with using jQuery's `_={timestamp}` hack (that's what `cache: false` does).

Comment: Thank your for your response.  I will look into this.